# Wordpress Admin Portal - Editor role Customization

Tags: php, wordpress

My Requirement is to Editors should able to see the posts which is added after the editor/user is created.

E.g., if WordPress system has over 2000 posts and editor is created on Dec 13th. once the editor logged into the WordPress admin he should able to see the posts after Dec 13th only.

I tried to add the filter to implement the change but its not working.  any suggestions?

```
function posts_since_editor_created($query)
{
    global $pagenow;
     if($pagenow != 'edit.php' || $query->is_admin )  //for admin and other places it returns the usual query response.
    {
        return $query;        
    }

    //check if current user have edit access
    if( current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) )
    {
        global $user_ID;
        $udata = get_userdata( $user_ID );
        $registered_date = $udata->user_registered;

        $query->set( 'date_query', 
        [
            [
                'after' =>  $registered_date,  // posts only displayed after user registration date 
                'before' => '2025-10-10',
                'inclusive' => true,
            ]
        ] 
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_since_editor_created');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **date_query** with following way.

```
 $query->set('date_query', array(
            array(
                'after' =>  $registered_date,  // posts only displayed after user registration date 
                'before' => '2025-10-10',
                'inclusive' => true
            ),
        )
    );
```

Just replace date_query with above one it will work.